# Can we do something to inform users on "accepting" answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepted-answer

Too often in this board, there are good answers given with tons of upvotes, but the questioner **rarely** accepts the answer as the accepted answer, resulting in the person answering losing lots of potential reputation and resulting in people not wanting to give answers if they will never be accepted.

I know that there are no real right or wrong answers regarding many of the workplace questions because they are so subjective to each person, but can we have a system where if a certain answer gets enough upvotes within a certain time period that it becomes automatically accepted?

[This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48467/is-it-rude-to-eat-drink-in-front-of-a-colleague-who-is-fasting-during-ramadan/48469#48469) is a great example. I get tons of people agreeing, lots of upvotes, but **no accepting** and this has happened multiple times to me now. I have to admit it is a little frustrating.

Comment: Well to be fair that answer/question is less than 24 hours old. Sometimes as an asker it can be good to wait longer as a newer answer can more completely and comprehensively your question. I've had a few times where I got an "accept" after posting an answer later than and which got fewer total votes but (apparently) better answered the question.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I absolutely _loathe_ the "auto accept" systems that other sites have. MSDN has this process where their site moderators decide if an answer "fixes your problem" and basically force you to accept an answer. I cannot possibly express my distaste and dislike of that system enough...

Comment: Fair enough. I just noticed that this situation happens in this board way more often than Stack Overflow for example because of the ubiquitous nature of "right and wrong" in workplace issues.

Comment: A lot of folks here too are 1-off accounts where people ask a question and never login again or never return. In your case, [the asker has accepted answers on all other questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/30165/learner?tab=questions) so I think just being patient is probably your best bet.

Comment: @enderland As someone who relies on sites like that I can't agree more - there's nothing more infuriating than reading a whole thread based on the presumption it was solved only to find some moderator decided arbitrarily that 'xyz' fixed it

Answer (score -1):

The questioner [gets a notification every time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275712/41688) their question is answered, so short of shocking them through the keyboard, there's no way to **force** them to accept an answer.

Accept that some questions will never have an accepted answer, so if you find a relevant question that *has* answers, try them! Even better: some accepted answers don't work (new releases break things) or are not as good as other answers. So try those, too!

If you're frustrated that you aren't getting the little green checkbox next to your answer, perhaps take a step back and ask yourself *why* you are doing all this. Is it to get more "karma"/bragging rights/etc or is it to help the questioner—and future people—resolve their problem?